# Asp.net webforms HttpClient.PostAsync - Goes to sleep mode - DeadLock

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, webforms, httpclient

I am using a library for communicate with a crypto api.
In Console Application every thing is ok about `async post`.
But in webforms it goes to sleep and nothing happens!
Just loading mode.
Here is the method   :

```
private async Task<WebCallResult<T>> PostAsync<T>(string url, object obj = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    using (var client = GetHttpClient())
    {
        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj ?? new object());
        var response = await client.PostAsync($"{url}", new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"), cancellationToken);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        // Return
        return this.EvaluateResponse<T>(response, content);
    }
}

private HttpClient GetHttpClient()
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        AllowAutoRedirect = false
    };
    var client = new HttpClient(handler);
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(this.EndpointUrl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    return client;
}
```

In line `var response =` web site goes to loading mode.
No error - Nothing - Just Loading.
How can i fix this problem in webforms?
In Console Application it is working fine.
Maybe i should change something in `Web.config`!!!
[Here is the library](https://github.com/burakoner/BitGo)

Comment: I am so sad about this issue - I worked so hard on that library in Console Application. In Console i have no error and every thing is ok. I do n't know what is problem in web forms.

Comment: I see in your library that you are creating synchronous wrappers for async methods. If you are using those then you are deadlocking. You can find many resources on deadlocking here and on the web. Incidentally [you should not create new HttpClients for each request](https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/)

Comment: Why in Console App there is no such that problem?

Comment: Console applications do not have a synchronization context, web forms does. You can learn about it with some research

Comment: What should i do? - changing that library is very difficult. I need a trick about web forms to work with that library.

Comment: You can apply `.ConfigureAwait(false);` to your awaitables but [be careful doing that](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: You have to apply ConfigureAwait everywhere, all the way down all of the code paths. It is by far better to not block on async code as mentioned in the article I linked to. I don't suppose it is practical to stop using WebForms and build your project in something from the current century?

Comment: Thanks my friend, Worked.

Comment: Just please be sure to read that article. If you introduce some new library that does not do this then it will break and there will be nothing you can do except find an alternative to that library.

Comment: I read that blog - Please put it as answer.